# Travis CI: one virtual machine for all stages

Tags: travis-ci

I have a test and deploy stage in my .travis.yml. And travis will do a yarn install for both test and deploy stages. So I'm wondering, is it possible to just do both stages in one virtual machine to prevent running yarn install twice? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this seems to be a design decision:

> It is important to note that jobs do not share storage, as each job runs in a fresh VM or container. If your jobs need to share files (e.g., using build artifacts from the “Test” stage for deployment in the subsequent “Deploy” stage), you need to use an external storage mechanism such as S3 and a remote scp server.
>
> — [Travis Docs: Build Stages](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/build-stages#data-persistence-between-stages-and-jobs)

Comment: Thanks, sounds like I just need to separate them into 2 jobs then